# VBA to read ChildNode of ChildNode of ChildNode in XML

Tags: xml, vba, excel

First of all "Thanks" for you time in looking into this.

I would be really thankful if someone could give me a sample code / snippet for solving the issue.
I am facing difficulty reading ChildNode of ChildNode  of ChildNode ... in XML through VBA.

sample XML : [sample XML file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3ja43n37m3y9ab/TEST_xml.xml?dl=0)

My current code gives the error: RUN TIME ERROR 6 OVERFLOW.

I want the output to be like this

```
ID       VIEW DESCRIPTION   COLUMNNAME
55494   Asset Management        Actual Price.Value
55464   Change Management      CAB Manager ( Change Co-ord )
55464   Change Management       Manufacturer (2)
55464   Change Management       Change Timing
55308   Incident Management     Submitter
55308   Incident Management     Submit Date
55308   Incident Management     Secure Work Log
55308   Incident Management     Number of Attachments
73189   Knowledge Management    
73189   Knowledge Management    ArticleCompany
73189   Knowledge Management    ArticleDocID
```

**Current CODE**

```
Sub test()
Dim Init As Integer
Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
Dim DomNode1  As IXMLDOMElement
Dim DomNode2  As IXMLDOMElement
Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
Dim childNode1 As IXMLDOMNode
Dim childNode2 As IXMLDOMNode
Dim childNode6 As IXMLDOMNode
Dim elements As Object
Dim el As Variant

Init = 7

'Worksheets("Report_Details").Select
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\DRIVE\BMC\DSS\01_DSS_NExT\SP_1\IN APP\Automation_YF\Tools\TEST_xml.xml")
child_count = 0
For Each DomNode1 In xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("view")
For Each childNode1 In DomNode1.getElementsByTagName("id")
For Each childNode2 In DomNode1.getElementsByTagName("viewDescription")
For Each childNode6 In DomNode1.getElementsByTagName("columnName")

                    ActiveSheet.Cells(Init, 6).Value2 = childNode6.Text
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Init, 2).Value2 = childNode2.Text
ActiveSheet.Cells(Init, 1).Value2 = childNode1.Text

child_count = child_count + 1
Init = Init + 1
                   Next childNode6
              Next childNode2
Next childNode1
Next DomNode1
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the desired output for the example XML you give. BTW the XML is not well formed; everything below the first line shoudl be enclosed in `<root> ... </root>`.

Comment: The XML is huge and the message has limitation on number of lines. I am trying to figure that.

Comment: Sure, but for those few lines of XML you wrote in your question, what would the output be?

Comment: The output i get with my current code is only for ID and viewDescription. Unless i comment out the line "For Each childNode6 In DomNode1.getElementsByTagName("columnName")" i get runtime 6 error overflow

Comment: I have changed my question output and provided the complete xml file in drop box.Hope I am clear now. Please suggest

Comment: please need some help on this

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SelectNodes()` and `SelectSingleNode()` passing suitable XPath expression as parameter, for example :

```
Init = 7
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\DRIVE\BMC\DSS\01_DSS_NExT\SP_1\IN APP\Automation_YF\Tools\vw_pun_atm_dv04.xml")
For Each DomNode1 In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//view[id and viewDescription and columnName]")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Init, 6).Value2 = DomNode1.SelectSingleNode("./id").Text
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Init, 2).Value2 = DomNode1.SelectSingleNode("./viewDescription").Text
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Init, 1).Value2 = DomNode1.SelectSingleNode("./columnName").Text
    Init = Init + 1
Next DomNode1
```

Comment: With a slight change in your code 
Init = 7
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\DRIVE\BMC\DSS\01_DSS_NExT\SP_1\IN APP\Automation_YF\Tools\vw_pun_atm_dv04.xml")
For Each DomNode1 In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//view[id and viewDescription]")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Init, 1).Value2 = DomNode1.SelectSingleNode("./id").Text
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Init, 2).Value2 = DomNode1.SelectSingleNode("./viewDescription").Text
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Init, 3).Value2 = DomNode1.SelectSingleNode("./fieldList/viewField/columnName").Text
    Init = Init + 1
Next DomNode1
it does not loop through and gives me only one row for each id